# Can't add a fourth variable to my table in R

Tags: r

I'm learning R for my class and one of our assignments is to create a graphical description of the density of trees in trial spaces using given data. I managed to attach the mother tree to the two trials I was assigned, but I can't figure out how to get the densities to show up as well. I attempted to create box and whisker plots out of what I had as well but it's very unlikely that what I did is correct. Any ideas?

This is the code that I have so far

```
library(tidyverse)
library(janitor)


rad <- radiata %>% 
filter(trial == "RO944_98" | trial == "RO947_99") %>% 
mutate(trial = factor(trial),
     mum = factor(mum), density = factor(density))

xtabs(~ mum + trial = rad)
select(rad, mum, trial, density)

rad %/%
filter(trial == "RO944_98" | trial == "RO947_99") %>% 
select(mum, trial, density) %/%
xtabs(~ mum + trial + density= rad)


radiata %>% tabyl(mum, trial, density) -> outside

boxplot(density ~ trial == "R0944_98", data = rad)

boxplot(density ~ trial == "R0947_99", data = rad)`
```

``

Comment: Welcome to SO!  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  Here, your example is not reproducible because we don't have access to your data.  You can provide it using by adding the output from `dput(radiata)` to your question.

Comment: Also note that for your plots, you can always paste in images to SO so we can see what the results of your plotting code gave you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.